# Errors using a LINQ query in a Silverlight application

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to consume the WCF services using Silverlight application in Sharepoint.

It's going to display all the data from a list in a grid. Somehow it is throwing a error.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'system.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.
>
> using the generic type 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable' requires 1 type arguments
>
> SLprojectsCRUD2010WCF.sharepointservice.list1item' is a type but is used like a variable.

How can this be solved?

```
private SharePointService.SkinnyBlondeDataContext _context;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(LayoutRoot_Loaded);
}

private void ShowProjects()
{
    // Declare the LINQ query
    var projectsQuery = (from p in _context.Tasks
                            select p) as DataServiceQuery<SharePointService.TasksItem>;
    // Execute the LINQ query
    projectsQuery.BeginExecute((IAsyncResult asyncResult) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {                // Runs in the UI thread
        // EndExecute returns
        IEnumerable < TasksItem > this.dataGridProjects.ItemsSource = projectsQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult).ToList();
    }), projectsQuery);
}

private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the context
    _context = new SharePointService.SkinnyBlondeDataContext(
                new Uri("http://vanir0269/_vti_bin/listdata.svc", UriKind.Absolute));
    ShowProjects();
}
```

Comment: Please format your post. I would normally do it for you, but it's in a *dreadful* state, and you can probably do it more easily straight from the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Until your source code is formatted properly it'll be a pain to see what the LINQ problem is, but the lambda expression problem is easy: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` takes a `Delegate`, and lambda expressions can only be converted into *specific* delegate types. This is easy to fix:

```
projectsQuery.BeginExecute((IAsyncResult asyncResult) => {
    Action action = () => {
        // Code in here
    };
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, null);
});
```